# a11y: Input fields, wrapped in a div, attached "by id" to a label

Tags: html, label, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a time picker component, composed by two separate `input` fields that work together to create the illusion of being one.

This is how the skeleton looks like

```
<div> {/* component container */}

    <div> {/* container for hours:minutes */}
        <input /> {/* hours */}
        <input /> {/* minutes */}
    </div>

    <Select /> {/* custom React component, for AM/PM */}
</div>
```

Everything works great for "regular" users, but the accessibility is poor.

Because of pre-existing limitation in the codebase, it's hard for me to simply wrap everything in a `label`, which would solve my problem.

---

What I'm thinking of doing is the following, and  I would like the community input (ha!) on whether this can be really useful to a screen reader or not.

```
<label htmlFor="myUniqueId">Here goes my label</label>
<div id="myUniqueId"> {/* component container */}

    <div> {/* container for hours:minutes */}
        <input /> {/* hours */}
        <input /> {/* minutes */}
    </div>

    <Select /> {/* custom React component, for AM/PM */}
</div>
```

So basically, set an ID on the container, instead of the inputs, and then attach a label using `htmlFor`.

Would this work for screen readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [`for` attribute must point at a `labelable` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#the-label-element):

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with
>   which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified,
>   the attribute’s value must be the ID of a labelable element in the
>   same Document as the label element.

[`labelable` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#labelable-element) are: `input`, `button`, `select`, `textarea`, `fieldset`, `output`, `object`, `meter`, `progress`, `label`, `img`.

I would structure it this way:

```
<label htmlFor="myUniqueId">Select time</label>
<fieldset id="myUniqueId"> {/* component container */}

    <div> {/* container for hours:minutes */}
        <input aria-label="hours" /> {/* hours */}
        <input aria-label="minutes" /> {/* minutes */}
    </div>

    <Select aria-label="AM or PM" /> {/* custom React component, for AM/PM */}
</fieldset>
```